# Help with regular expressions

Tags: regex

Here is my regex: `(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)=([A-Za-z0-9, _.]+|^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))`

I was hoping i could use something like this to match text in a config file of the forms:

```
variable=value
ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

etc...

with the test string

```
test=127.0.0.1
test1=192.168.0.1
test2=hello world
test3=helloworld
test4=Carl_Sagan,Awesome,cool story bro
test5=%should not match(#$&!&$(5vzxcv
6test=should not match
```

I was testing on http://myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab and some others

and this expression would only match the first line. When I cut out different parts of the expression, it worked how I wanted, but not when I put them together.

On the testing site http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it works just fine.

`^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))` will return all the ip address in the test string

`(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)=` will return all the `variable=` on the page

`[A-Za-z0-9, _.]+` will return almost anything

Can you guys help me understand what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: The major thing you are doing wrong is not explaining what you want. Given your input above, what is your desired output?

Comment: Which language do you use? Your regex matches each of the lines separately. Do you instead want to match anything with only one regex?

Comment: @Bohemian The desired output is every line except the ones that say should not match. which are the last two. It only gives me the first one.

Comment: Using [pretty much the same regex, just condensed](http://regexr.com?2ubgi) I was able to match the lines you spoke of...

Comment: @Howard the target language is c using regex.h, but I am just testing in some online regex testers.

Comment: @Brad Christie Thanks, I'm just not really sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Brad Christie On your regex tester, my original expression works fine as well. Your new one does not work at all on the ones I was using before. Why is that?

Comment: If it only matched the first line, you probably forgot to specify the Multiline option.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using regex for ip adresses. Othervise you will have to deal with beasts like

```
"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

Comment: I'm not going for a very complex match on the ip address. I'm just going to let them specify a min and max to try and it will iterate up. It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: plus I can just copy pasta your statement into my regex and bam, I don't even have to deal with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)=(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3,5}[0-9]{1,3}|([A-Za-z0-9, _.]*))
```

Check it out here: http://regexr.com?2ubgl

Comment: did you just switch the last two groups?

Comment: I also added an extra capture group around both of them.  That was the key.  I switched them because the one that you had first will match IP addresses, so they would never get captured separately.